# Uso de condicinais em macros

Tags: c, compilação

Boa noite! Quero testar uma condição que será implementada na macro. O valor para o teste será informado pelo usuário. Meu código gera um erro na hora de compilar. O que pode ser? Obrigado!

```
#include <stdio.h>.
#define Epar(x)((x)%2)?1:0

int main()
{
    int x;
    printf("Informe um numero: \n\n");
    scanf("%d", x);
    Epar(x);
}
```

Comment: É sintomático que não tenha colocado o erro. O erro nada tem a ver com a macro. Na verdade acho bastante desnecessário o uso desta macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você faz uso de macro para verificar se o valor de x é par. Além disso, faz uso do operador ternário, que é uma alternativa para substituir o *if-else*. Pois bem, relembrando a sintaxe desse operador, temos a seguinte definição:

> condição ? verdadeiro : falso

Partindo dessa sintaxe, nota-se que não há uma condição bem definida na condição para o operador ternário, somente uma operação *(x % 2)*. Se o objetivo é verificar se o valor x é par, o correto é utilizar *((x % 2) == 0)*, pois assim há verificação do resultado da operação e será possível retornar 1 para casos verdadeiros e 0 para casos falsos.

Dois erros são aparentes no seu código.

i. O caractere . (ponto) está em um local inadequado na definição da biblioteca stdio.h - o que levará o compilador a apontar um erro de *extra tokens*.

```
#include <stdio.h>.
```

ii. Na etapa de atribuição de valor à variável x, o operador & está ausente - o que impossibilita a leitura do dado inserido.

```
scanf("%d", x);
```

Destaca-se também um ponto interessante: como as macros são substituições de *strings*, é uma boa prática de programação utilizar parênteses em torno de seus elementos - principalmente para garantir que precedências de operadores sejam tratadas da forma correta.

Diante do exposto, o seu código compilará sem erros desta forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define Epar(x) ((((x) % 2) == 0) ? 1 : 0)

int main()
{
    int x;
    printf("Informe um numero: \n\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    if(Epar(x))
    {
        printf("\nNumero par");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nNumero impar");
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado! Realmente me passei ao adicionar aquele ponto na diretiva (acredito que tenha errado na hora de digitar).

Answer (score 0):

Aquele ponto após o `#include <stdio.h>` certamente vai fazer com que o compilador retorne um erro como esse:

```
teste.c:1:19: warning: extra tokens at end of #include directive [enabled by default]
 #include <stdio.h>.
                   ^
```

Segue um código corrigido e testado capaz de resolver o seu problema:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define EhPar(x)    (!(x % 2))

int main()
{
    int n;

    printf("Informe um numero: ");
    scanf( "%d", &n );

    if( EhPar( n ) )
    {
        printf("%d eh um numero par!\n", n );
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d eh um numero impar!\n", n );
    }

    return 0;
}
```